# How to upload file from Unix to Microsoft SharePoint URL?

Tags: bash, shell, email, unix, sharepoint

I am attempting to upload a file from a Unix machine to a Microsoft SharePoint URL within a shell script. The SharePoint is setup to accept emails with attachments. When an email with an attachment is sent to the URL, the file is uploaded. I am unable to get the same functionality from within my script using the `mailx` command.

**My attempt:**

```
uuencode $fullPath ${file} | mailx -m -s "Outage Report" $spEmail
```

My attempt works when sending to a personal email (files are sent as attachments), but the files are not uploaded when using my SharePoint URL.

I have tested the SharePoint URL by mailing from my personal email (via Outlook) and the files are uploaded correctly.

**Q:** Why am I unable to mail files from the script directly to the SharePoint?

[Add content to sites by sending e-mail - Office Support](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Add-content-to-sites-by-sending-e-mail-b989a9f3-14de-4e59-9faf-b843ec40cabb)